# Limit courses creation in the front end per user role

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I'm trying to set a limit to course creation using the roles of S2Member. For example for the level one, the user can create only 2 courses and 2 units. I added this code but it works only from the back-end. In the front-end creation (using wplms theme) the user can still create new courses and units. I'm not expert in coding, just trying to find my way out to this functionality. Any suggestions please?

```js
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'check_post_limit' );
function check_post_limit() {
    global $userdata;
    global $post_type;
    global $wpdb;

 if( $post_type === 'course' ) {
  $item_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'course' AND post_author = $userdata->ID" );
  if(( $item_count >= 2 ) && (current_user_is("s2member_level1")) ) { wp_die( "Do not create too much courses." ); }
 } elseif( $post_type === 'unit' ) {
  $shopinfo_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'unit' AND post_author = $userdata->ID" );
  if(( $item_count >= 2 ) && (current_user_is("s2member_level1")) ) { wp_die( "Do not create too much units." ); }
 }
 return;
}
```

Comment: There is an extraneous quote on line 10 - if((" $item_count

Comment: corrected, but is not efficient now, user still can create courses above the limit

Comment: @user2182349 Sorry I don't understand how to do so, can ou guide me please

Comment: I was wrong about the braces, that was an older version of PHP.  Use var_dump($item_count) to see what the value is.  HTH

Comment: ok the above code is working fine in the back end; not in the front end creation (using wplms theme)